# How to remove object from database on tab close django

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have an image loaded on-page and it's loaded from the database and I want to remove that object from the database when the tab is close how can I do that?
framework- Django

Comment: There is no way to detect that in Django, but there are (limited) strategies to handle it in JavaScript.

Comment: I would suggest using a combination of javascript's `beforeunload` event handler, an AJAX POST call (pass in image id) and then delete object in your view.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it's doable with Django, but to fulfil your requirement you can rather store that image in session instead of a database.

Comment: how to store images in session?

Comment: ok since you were using database previously its safe to say you are good with models in Django, right? So here how you might do it; you will upload image user provided in your media_url [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/static-files/) and save its URL in js session or Django(if Django supports session).